# values not being passed onto process.php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The script below helps with processing of a form that request number and name values, and than sends it to process.php and also displays a confirmation and hides the button that would fired the modal to the form so user cannot retry to fill the form.

Script to handle pass data to process.php

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

function successHandler(){
    console.log('Success');
    $("#thanks").html(msg);
    $('#form-content').modal('hide');
}

function errorHandler(){
    console.log('Error');
    alert("Error");
}

var nameval = $('#name').val();
var numberval = $('#number').val();

$("form#contact").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {
            name: nameval,
            number: numberval,
            submit: true 
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $("#thanks").html(msg);
            $('#form-content').modal('hide');
            return false;
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

The whole action does generate an email with HTML from the process.php script but does not include the data that was captured from the form, I believe there is a error within this script as I cannot find anything on the form or process.php that is using PHPMail() doing anything wrong.

Could you help?

**Update**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = ($_POST['name']);
$number = ($_POST['number']);
echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\">THANKS! SUBMITTED</span>";

$to = "EMAIL BLANKED";
$subject = "Alert!";

$message = "name: $name number: $number";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <email blank>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
 else { echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Error</div>' ; }
?>
```

Comment: There is no JS error ?

Comment: Update question along with your `PHP` code and even if there is no error then give the full Path within your `url`

Comment: Can you share your php code also?

Comment: @AkramFares no there isn't and it does all perfectly except sending the data from the form 'Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK'

Comment: Try putting `var nameval = $('#name').val();
var numberval = $('#number').val();`  after `$("form#contact").submit(function(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put this two lines:

```
var nameval = $('#name').val();
var numberval = $('#number').val();
```

inside the submit function like this

```
$("form#contact").submit(function(){
var nameval = $('#name').val();
var numberval = $('#number').val();
```

because if you set the values of the variables before the submission of the form the inputs will most likely be empty.